# How can I dynamically share links through Facebook Graph API?

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to send unique links through facebook, but I want the option to send it as a message, post it on my wall, or post it on a friends wall. Something similar to the send button, but with more functionality and the ability to specify which link I want to send. How do I do with with FB Graph?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is with the [Facebook JS SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) using [Dialogs](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.ui/)

- To send as a message, change the 'method' parameter to 'send'
- To post on your wall, change the 'method' parameter to 'feed'
- To post to a friends wall, add a 'to' parameter and then specify the friends ID that you want to post to.